# Rust Mutable Iterator over Cols of Matrix with flat Representation

Tags: rust

I have a matrix that is stored in an `Vec<T>` with a row-major representation.
In my code I often end up writing something like

```
for i in 0..width {
    for j in 0..height {
        let element = matrix.get_mut(i, j);
        // do something
    }
}
```

That does of course work, but I think the ergonomics would be nicer if I could use iterators. Imagine a function with the return type of `fn cols_mut() -> impl ExactSizeIterator<Item = impl ExactSizeIterator<Item = &mut T>>`.
Then I could do something like

```
matrix.cols_mut.for_each(|col| {
    col.fold(0, |sum, val| {
        *val += sum;
        *val
    });
});
```

Writing a non mutable version is pretty straightforward

```
fn cols(&self) -> impl ExactSizeIterator<Item = impl ExactSizeIterator<Item = &T>> {
    (0..self.width()).map(move |i| {
        (0..self.height()).map(move |j| {
            self.get(i, j).unwrap()
        })
    })
}
```

but I just can't figure out how to satisfy the borrow checker when making this mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** often do your processing that way, I recommend you to switch to column-major representation because processing matrix against it representation lead to a lot of cache misses and prevents autovectorization.

As for your question, it is possible with unsafe and pointer arithmetics.

```rust
// This is to show that we have row-major matrix.
fn calc_idx(row: usize, col: usize, total_rows: usize, total_cols: usize) -> usize {
    assert!((row < total_rows) & (col < total_cols));
    row * total_cols + col
}

fn make_column_iterators<'matrix, T: Sized + 'matrix>(
    matrix: &'matrix mut [T],
    rows: usize,
    cols: usize,
) -> impl ExactSizeIterator<Item = impl ExactSizeIterator<Item = &'matrix mut T> + 'matrix> {
    assert_eq!(matrix.len(), rows * cols);
    let ptr = matrix.as_mut_ptr();
    (0..cols).map(move |col_idx| unsafe {
        // SAFETY: We are in range because `col_idx < cols`.
        let ptr = ptr.add(col_idx);
        (0..rows)
            // SAFETY: Indices (i < rows, j < cols)
            // in range.
            .map(move |row_idx| ptr.add(row_idx*cols))
            // Function lifetime arguments prevent aliasing
            // matrix and individual references.
            // We take reference to each element exactly once.
            .map(|p| &mut *p)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for this response. Cols is just a motivating example. I actually need to iterate over my matrix in all 4 directions, so I can’t have it fast both ways. 
Having to use unsafe isn’t great, but it works. Thank you for posting it